# How to debug the SPARQL queries sent to remote triplestore in GraphDB ? (binding of variables in SERVICE clause)

Tags: sparql, graphdb

When writing a SPARQL query to my local GraphDB instance using a SERVICE keyword that queries a remote triplestore, how can I debug the query that is actually sent to the remote triplestore ?

My problem is that I used a subselect in my local graph that is supposed to bind some variables that should be passed to the SERVICE clause, but they probably are not. I need to understand how the SERVICE clause is executed.

Apart from subselect, is there anything else I can do to control the order or execution between the local query and the SERVICE clause ?

My query skeleton is

```
SELECT ?localUri ?remoteUri
WHERE {

  # subselect : should be executed first
  {
  SELECT ?localUri ?remoteReference
  WHERE {
    # here : build/select ?remoteReference
  }
  }


  # SERVICE : should be executed with ?remoteReference bound
  SERVICE <http://remoteService> {
    ?remoteUri ex:reference ?remoteReference .
  }

}
```

It seems the SERVICE clause is executed without the ?remoteReference variable being bound.

FWIW the remote service is a Virtuoso triplestore at http://publications.europa.eu/webapi/rdf/sparql

Thanks !

Comment: you can use Wireshark and filter for http requests on the remote endpoint. In your case put `ip.dst=54.154.48.65 && http` into the filter text field.

Comment: other than that, you can also try to start GraphDB with `./graphdb -Dreuse.vars.in.subselects`